# WPF-DataGridTemplate Column of DataGrid are not available in code behind when trying to access with DataRowView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The below code is my WPF `DataGrid` XAML. I try to access the data grid template column with checkbox  in code behind

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="wdgVinpaymentDetail" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanUserDeleteRows="True"   Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.4' }" CanUserAddRows="False" LoadingRow="WdgVinpaymentDetail_LoadingRow" Loaded="WdgVinpaymentDetail_Loaded" IsReadOnly="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="btnDeleteVin">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Delete" x:Name="DeleteVIN" IsEnabled="True"  Click="DeleteVIN_Click"
                       Command="Delete"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Select" Header="Select" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectAll"   Checked="ChkSelectAll_Checked" Unchecked="ChkSelectAll_Unchecked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="chkSelect" Click="ChkSelect_Click"  ></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sl. No." Width ="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.04' }"  x:Name="RALNSLNO"  Binding="{Binding RALNSLNO}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VIN" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.12' }"  x:Name="RALNVIN"  Binding="{Binding RALNVIN}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="NSP" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.08' }" x:Name="RALNUAMT" Binding="{Binding RALNUAMT}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VATamt"  Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.04' }" x:Name="VATamt" Binding="{Binding VATamt}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="VAT%" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.04' }" x:Name="VATper" Binding="{Binding VATper}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="OthExpn" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }"  x:Name="TotalOthExpn" Binding="{Binding TotalOthExpn}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="OthExpnvat" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }"  x:Name="TotalOthExpnvat" Binding="{Binding TotalOthExpnvat}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total"  Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }"  x:Name="Total" Binding="{Binding Total}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hoprice"  Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }"  x:Name="Hoprice" Binding="{Binding HoPrice}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rpdno" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }"  x:Name="Rpdno" Binding="{Binding Rpdno}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rpdprice" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="Rpdprice" Binding="{Binding Rpdprice}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Errflg" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="Errflg" Binding="{Binding Errflg}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ptag" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="RALNRFNO2" Binding="{Binding RALNRFNO}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model Code" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="STMOCD" Binding="{Binding STMOCD}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Character Code" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="STCHCD" Binding="{Binding STCHCD}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model Year" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="STMOYR" Binding="{Binding STMOYR}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Manufacturing Year" Width = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={local1:RatioConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.07' }" x:Name="STMFYR" Binding="{Binding STMFYR}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my code behind i try to access the select checkbox

```cs
private void WdgVinpaymentDetail_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DataRowView dr in wdgVinpaymentDetail.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chk = dr.Row[1] as CheckBox;
            checkboxes.Add(chk);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

However the first two `datagridtemplatecolumns` are not available in `datarowview` with this code
when i use this dr.Row[1] i get the fourth value VIN ,dr[0] is Sl.No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Andy post i did the following corrections,i got an extra column CHKSEL as false while fetching data from database .
Then my xaml was changed like this

```
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Select" Header="Select" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                      <CheckBox x:Name="chkSelectAll"   Checked="ChkSelectAll_Checked" Unchecked="ChkSelectAll_Unchecked"  />
                     </DataTemplate>
                      </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                      <CheckBox  x:Name="chkSelect"  IsChecked="{Binding CHKSEL}"  ></CheckBox>
                      </DataTemplate>
                      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The datatable has false in CHKSEL and the IsChecked attribute is binded with CHKSEL ,so at  load time it is always uncheked

In my code behind checked and unchecked statement ,i get the datatable which was binded to itemsource property of my grid,change the CHKSEL value to true in datatable  and then set ItemSource to updated datatable,for unchecked function set value to false in dattable and then bind

```
private void ChkSelectAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)e.OriginalSource;

                if (checkbox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    DataTable ldtDetails = (DataTable)App.Current.Properties["CancelDetail"];
                    for(int i = 0; i <= ldtDetails.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        ldtDetails.Rows[i][0] = "true";
                    }
                    wdgVinpaymentDetail.ItemsSource = null;
                    wdgVinpaymentDetail.ItemsSource = ldtDetails.DefaultView;
                    App.Current.Properties["CancelDetail"] = ldtDetails;
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
       

        }

        private void ChkSelectAll_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)e.OriginalSource;

                if (checkbox.IsChecked == false)
                {
                    DataTable ldtDetails = (DataTable)App.Current.Properties["CancelDetail"];
                    for (int i = 0; i <= ldtDetails.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        ldtDetails.Rows[i][0] = "false";
                    }
                    wdgVinpaymentDetail.ItemsSource = null;
                    wdgVinpaymentDetail.ItemsSource = ldtDetails.DefaultView;
                    App.Current.Properties["CancelDetail"] = ldtDetails;
                }
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood what datarowview is.

It's all about the data connected to the itemssource of a datagrid rather than the UI this is templated into.

Datarowview doesn't contain controls at all.

It contains a view of the data presented to that row.

I'm not sure whether when wpf was being designed they built it deliberately with the intention of everyone working with binding and MVVM. Way back when I learnt WPF as I worked on projects, I quickly realised this is the easiest way to work with WPF.  Manipulating UI by working directly with controls or using UI as a data source is hard work. My advice would be not to work that way.

I don't know where you're headed with this, but work with bound data. Whether that's a datatable or Observablecollection of row viewmodels, work with that.

Comment: Thank you,i kind of did it the wrong way then .Unfortunately we have been told not to use MVVM ,so i do View related stuff in code behind ,and all the solutions in internet are mostly in MVVM

Comment: Somehow, you're setting items or itemssource. Work with the rows of that collection. One of these is a datarowview. But realise this is your data rather than controls.